# Display HTML-mail in Rails and sanitize javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, escaping, sanitization, strip

I'm working on a webmail alike application.
What ist the best solution to escape 'bad' characters and strings like '' etc.?
Common HTML-Tags such as ul, br, img etc. should still be interpreted by the browser as valid HTML.
I already played arround with rgrove/sanitize but the results weren't promising, besides i need to escape, not sanitize the bad characters.

-e-

i'm using DHTMLX, maybe i can use one of it's components?

-e2-

i now display the mail content in a iframe. But i still need to get rid of javascript in the mails, any help?

Comment: same unanswered question here. opened an issue to sanitize: https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/issues/98